# youcompleteme can't autotrigger when typing. I had to press `<C-space>` to trigger

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

How does YCM autotrigger without hotkey <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd>?

Comment: check if the number of chars required for autotrigger is set properly. `let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion = 2`

Comment: Also check if auto-trigger is activated `let g:ycm_auto_trigger = 1`

Comment: @knightrider they're already set by default.

Comment: Yes they are set by default. But just make sure that they are set properly. Maybe it was reset accidentally in your vimrc. May be someother plugin is causing issues. I would update and recompile ycm, force the config which I told above. If it still wont work, I would start disabling other plugins till I find the problem.

Comment: @knightrider there is only YCM one plugin.

Comment: U meant you are only using YCM plugin?

Comment: @knightrider No. I install spf13-vim firstly and enable YCM, but YCM can't  autotrigger. Then, I test YCM independently.